# Jquery Searching for text

Tags: jquery

I'm rather new to Javascript in general. Using Jquery, I'm trying to select some text stored in a h2 tag with an ID "subHeaderID," then I want to check if the string is empty or null and if not execute some code. I've tried the following:

```
if('#subheaderID'.text){
     $('#subheaderID').text('');    }
else
{
     alert('#subheaderID'.text);
     $('#subheaderID').text("foo:");
}
```

However, this always results in the else block being called. The content of subheaderID.text is "undefined." As such, I tried:

```
if('#subheaderID'.text != null){
    $('#subheaderID').text('');
}
else
{
   alert('#subheaderID'.text);
   $('#subheaderID').text("foo:");
}
```

This results in the if block being called, but only if the string is undefined—not when the string is assigned to be empty. As such, I tried the following code:

```
if('#subheaderID'.text != null && '#subheaderID'.text !== ''){
    $('#subheaderID').text('');
}
else
{
   alert('#subheaderID'.text);
   $('#subheaderID').text("foo:");
}
```

Yet, unfortunately, this results in the else block always being called. If someone could give me some guidence I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when using jQuery, you access elements as jQuery objects. objects require `$()`. by rewriting,

```
if(!'#subheaderID'.text){
```

as

```
if(!$('#subheaderID').text()) {
```

you should be able to continue with your checks.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, it wasn't me. Thanks for the information. I made those adjustments.

Comment: Yup, it worked. Thanks so much, I'm not used to Javascript's tendency to quietly break when you do something wrong. I almost strictly develop in C++

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong at if block

Instead of

```
if('#subheaderID'.text){
```

You should

```
if(!$('#subheaderID').text()){
```